# How to render MDX with Gatsby 5?

Tags: gatsby, mdxjs

Since updating to Gatsby 5 and the latest version of gatsby-plugin-mdx (5.12.0) my markdown is rendered as-is, not HTML.

For instance this: `[foo](www.bar.com)` will literally be `[foo](www.bar.com)` on the web page instead of a link.

I load the plugin in gatsby-config, along with gatsby-source-filesystem

```json
{
resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: "terms",
    path: `${__dirname}/src/markdown/`,
  },
},
`gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
```

I get the body from Gatsby's GraphQL layer

```
query MyQuery {
  allMdx {
    nodes {
      body
    }
  }
}
```

And pass it to the MDXProvider and then... nothing happens.

```
import React from "react"
import { MDXProvider } from "@mdx-js/react"

export function RenderMDX(body: any) {
  return <MDXProvider>{body}</MDXProvider>
}
```

Pretty much all documentation is about rendering pages, I just want to render bits of Markdown in pages. What am I missing here?

Comment: Update: I'd mark this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74309351/how-to-render-mdx-with-gatsby-plugin-mdx-from-allmdx-query
But it doesn't have an accepted answer :|